# Getting null value in jasper report PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to implement jasper to pdf report in java. After setting parameter to jasper report, I'm getting `null` value to pdf.

Report's design:

[image: report1.jrxml]

Generated PDF file looks like:

[image: Test.pdf]

My code is :

```
String outputFile = "D://Test.pdf";
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("name", "raju");
JRDataSource datasource = new JREmptyDataSource();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report1.jrxml");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, datasource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D://Test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$P{name}` instead of `$F{name}` in that TextField expression.

`$P{...}` is used for parameters and `$F{...}` for fields (values provided by data source).

Comment: after editing Jasper Report source to $P{name} i am getting following error

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. Parameter not found : name
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
 at com.propellum.com.JasperMain.main(JasperMain.java:70)

Comment: Then you should at first define the _name_ parameter.

In JasperSoft Studio right click on **Parameters**, select **Create parameter** from the pop-up and then rename newly added _Parameter1_ on _name_. Or you can do it in jrxml by adding `<parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>` into the root `jasperReport` element.

See JasperSoft documentation on https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters for more information about parameters.

Comment: OK, perfect. Then if you can please accept the answer, thank you.